# How can I format DBML in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, dbml

I'm working on a project that uses [DBML](https://dbml.dbdiagram.io/docs/#index-definition) (Database Markup Language) to document the database schema. I'm using VS Code as my editor, but I can't find a way to format the DBML code automatically. How can I format DBML in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matt-meyers.vscode-dbml is working good for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).